# Script for swapping subfolders recursively

Tags: scripting

For days I am struggling with a problem.
I have a directory structure like:

```
   Dir/Documents/PersonA/
   Dir/Documents/PersonB/
   Dir/Pictures/PersonA/
   Dir/Pictures/PersonC/
   Dir/Mails/PersonA/
   Dir/Mails/PersonB/
```

And I would like to change it recursively with all content to:

```
   Dir/PersonA/Documents/
   Dir/PersonA/Pictures/
   Dir/PersonA/Mails/
   Dir/PersonB/Documents
   Dir/PersonB/Mails
   Dir/PersonC/Pictures
```

I tried some scripting, but got stuck because some of the dirs contain spaces, and because I am not good enough.....

Comment: Scripting in what?

Comment: bash or sh is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In shell (bash, sh, zsh, etc.), it could be with `for` loop:

```
for person in $(cd Dir/Documents/ ; ls); do
    for d in Documents Pictures Mails; do
        mv "Dir/$d/${person}" "Dir/${person}/$d"            
    done
done
```

EDIT: added double-quote around `mv` arguments

EDIT2: `for` isn't kind enough to deal with spaces. (+ add mkdir)

```
/bin/ls -d Dir/*/* | while read e; do
    persondir=$(echo $e | awk -F/ '{print $1"/"$3}')
    subfolder=$(echo $e | awk -F/ '{print $1"/"$3"/"$2}')
    mkdir -p "${persondir}"
    mv "$e" "$subfolder"
done
```

Comment: Because some folder names contain spaces, the loop in run on every part between the spaces. So a dir called "bike from mama" results in:
     mv: cannot stat 'Dir/Documents/Bike': No such file or directory

     mv: cannot stat 'Dir/Pictures/Bike': No such file or directory

     mv: cannot stat 'Dir/Mails/Bike': No such file or directory

     mv: cannot stat 'Dir/Documents/From': No such file or directory


etcetera

Comment: yes. With my little knowledge I tried $({person}) but this was not the solution..........

Comment: double-quotes would do the job properly.

Comment: No change, the quotes change the mv command, but the problem is in the loop, it goes too often through the loop because of the spaces. 2nd point => the mv command does not create directories. This command should be added in the loop also I guess?

Comment: Using bash I added IFS=$'\n' as first line. This helps a lot making the end of line character the only separator.